# Get traceback information including SyntaxError from compile()

Tags: python, exception, traceback

### Basic problem

It appears that `SyntaxError`s (and `TypeError`s) raised by the `compile()` function are **not** included in the stack trace returned by `sys.exc_info()`, but **are** printed as part of the formatted output using `traceback.print_exc`.

### Example

For example, given the following code (where `filename` is the name of a file that contains Python code with the line `$ flagrant syntax error`):

```
import sys
from traceback import extract_tb
try:
    with open(filename) as f:
        code = compile(f.read(), filename, "exec")
except:
    print "using sys.exc_info:"
    tb_list = extract_tb(sys.exc_info()[2])
    for f in tb_list:
        print f
    print "using traceback.print_exc:"
    from traceback import print_exc
    print_exc()
```

I get the following output (where `<scriptname>` is the name of the script containing the code above):

```
using sys.exc_info:
('<scriptname>', 6, 'exec_file', 'code = compile(f.read(), filename, "exec")')
using traceback.print_exc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<scriptname>", line 6, in exec_file
    code = compile(f.read(), filename, "exec")
  File "<filename>", line 3
    $ flagrant syntax error
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

### My questions

I have three questions:

- Why doesn't the traceback from `sys.exc_info()` include the frame where the `SyntaxError` was generated?
- How does `traceback.print_exc` get the missing frame info?
- What's the best way to save the "extracted" traceback info, including the `SyntaxError`, in a list? Does the last list element (i.e. the info from the stack frame representing where the `SyntaxError` occurred) need to be manually constructed using `filename` and the `SyntaxError` exception object itself?

---

### Example use-case

For context, here's the my use-case for trying to get a complete stack-trace extraction.

I have a program that essentially implements a DSL by `exec`ing some files containing user-written Python code. (Regardless of whether or not this is a good DSL-implementation strategy, I'm more or less stuck with it.) Upon encountering an error in the user code, I would (in some cases) like the interpreter to save the error for later rather than vomiting up a stack trace and dying. So I have a `ScriptExcInfo` class specifically made to store this information. Here's (a slightly edited version of) that class's `__init__` method, complete with a rather ugly workaround for the problem described above:

```
def __init__(self, scriptpath, add_frame):
    self.exc, tb = sys.exc_info()[1:]
    self.tb_list = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
    if add_frame:
        # Note: I'm pretty sure that the names of the linenumber and
        # message attributes are undocumented, and I don't think there's
        # actually a good way to access them.
        if isinstance(exc, TypeError):
            lineno = -1
            text = exc.message
        else:
            lineno = exc.lineno
            text = exc.text
        # '?' is used as the function name since there's no function context
        # in which the SyntaxError or TypeError can occur.
        self.tb_list.append((scriptpath, lineno, '?', text))
    else:
        # Pop off the frames related to this `exec` infrastructure.
        # Note that there's no straightforward way to remove the unwanted
        # frames for the above case where the desired frame was explicitly
        # constructed and appended to tb_list, and in fact the resulting
        # list is out of order (!!!!).
        while scriptpath != self.tb_list[-1][0]:
            self.tb_list.pop()
```

Note that by "rather ugly," I mean that this workaround turns what should be a single-argument, 4-line  `__init__` function to require two arguments and take up 13 lines.

Comment: ....this can't be THAT hard, can it? Come on, where's Martjin??

Comment: “Does the last list element (i.e. the info from the stack frame representing where the `SyntaxError` occurred) need to be manually constructed using filename and the `SyntaxError` exception object itself?” From the docstring on `print_exception`: “This differs from `print_tb()` in the following ways: […] (3) if type is `SyntaxError` and value has the appropriate format, it prints the line where the syntax error occurred with a caret on the next line indicating the approximate position of the error.”

Comment: In other words, yes, it is synthesized in `print_exc` and not really in the traceback. You will have to inspect the exception object and reconstruct it yourself, or reuse some code from `traceback` for that purpose.

Comment: Huh. I saw that, but I didn't realize it meant that the entire frame is missing from the traceback given by `exc_info`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **only** difference between your two approaches is that `print_exc()` prints a formatted exception. For a `SyntaxError` that includes formatting the information in that exception, which includes the actual line that caused the problem.

For the traceback itself, `print_exc()` uses `sys.exc_info()[2]`, the same information you are using already to produce the traceback. In other words, it doesn't get any more information than you already do, but you are ignoring the exception information itself:

```
>>> import traceback
>>> try:
...     compile('Hmmm, nope!', '<stdin>', 'exec')
... except SyntaxError as e:
...     print ''.join(traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e))
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    Hmmm, nope!
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here `traceback.format_exception_only()` is an undocumented function used by `traceback.print_exc()` to format the exception value. All the information is there for you to extract on the exception itself:

```
>>> dir(e)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', 'args', 'filename', 'lineno', 'message', 'msg', 'offset', 'print_file_and_line', 'text']
>>> e.args
('invalid syntax', ('<stdin>', 1, 11, 'Hmmm, nope!\n'))
>>> e.filename, e.lineno, e.offset, e.text
('<stdin>', 1, 11, 'Hmmm, nope!\n')
```

Also see the documentation of [`traceback.print_exception()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception):

> (3) if *type* is `SyntaxError` and value has the appropriate format, it prints the line where the syntax error occurred with a caret indicating the approximate position of the error.

and the [`SyntaxError` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError):

> Instances of this class have attributes `filename`, `lineno`, `offset` and `text` for easier access to the details. `str()` of the exception instance returns only the message.

That the line with the syntax error is not included in the traceback is only logical; code with a syntax error cannot be executed, so no execution frame was ever created for it. And the exception is being thrown by the `compile()` function, the bottom-most frame of execution.

As such you are stuck with your 'ugly' approach; it is the correct approach for handling `SyntaxError` exceptions. However, the attributes **are** documented.

Note that `exception.message` is normally set to `exception.args[0]`, and `str(exception)` *usually* gives you the same message (if `args` is longer you get `str(exception.args)` instead, although some exception types provide a custom `__str__` that often just gives you `exception.args[0]`).

Comment: "code with a syntax error cannot be executed, so no execution frame was ever created for it." ...Ah. Of course. Thank you.